# Strategy to Push Data from a Device Socket into SAP in Real Time

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-services, iot, low-latency

**NEED**: I need to create a **real-time**, **low latency** middleware that listens to a socket on a scanning device on a conveyor belt in a factory, and sends its read data up into SAP; all in-network.

**PROPOSAL**: At a high level, my idea is to write a Windows Service in C# using a `System.Net.Sockets` client to connect to the device, then push that up to SAP as it's read. My questions are specific to the Windows Service and TCP Sockets side (I can handle the SAP side).

I would like to receive a little conceptual guidance from someone experienced in Windows Services and Socket. Also, would I need to keep the socket always open in order to be listening for data, rights? I don't need an extensive answer or code; though I wouldn't object to either.

Perhaps this question would be better received in the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) community? I'm surely not the first to need a solution like this. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if I would use TCP and would consider using a Broadcast UDP.  TCP can require both the client and server to be restarted to get a connection to complete.  A broadcast message you can either restart the client or server at any time to restart the communications.  It sound like you are just receiving status and I would use a broadcast message.  Broadcast is also nice that you can simultaneously have multiple server listening to same data.

Comment: Wow, seriously guys? Downvote already? That didn't last a day. Give me a good reason this should be closed? Need I remind you? "[Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)," "[The War of the Closes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/)," and most importantly "[BE NICE!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback)."